# HTML5 - localStorage save and load

Tags: html

I am a very basic HTML5 programmer, looking to make a cookie clicker clone. The single problem with it is that there is no saving. Can somebody just tell me how to save and load variables basically? I am not expert to be honest, so sorry.

```
  function saveGame() {
    localStorage.removeItem('cookiesStorage')
    localStorage.setItem('cookiesStorage', cookies)
}
function loadGame() {
    cookies = localStorage.getItem('cookiesStorage')//keeps adding 0 to the end every second
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation or doing a tutorial or anything? If so, then you should have some code to show us and a specific question about that code that you want to ask.

Comment: i added the code, although the problem is the loadgame function keeps adding 0 to the end every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've still not provided enough code for me to know exactly what's wrong, but I can guess:

`localStorage` items are stored as strings. The result of `"0" + 0` is `"00"`. I suspect that's the reason that it "keeps adding 0 to the end every second"

You may want to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` when saving to and loading from `localStorage`.

Comment: Okay, i have changed my code, i made it be a basic localStorage JS function so now every time i refresh it, it changes the amount to the starting value again. Code: `function saveGame() {
  localStorage.setItem('cookiesAmount', cookies)
}

function loadGame() {
 localStorage.getItem(cookies)
}`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You've not provided enough of your code. What is expected to happen? What is actually happening? What have you tried? What have you searched for? Try making a copy of your project, and removing every part of it until ONLY this issue remains, and then post all of that code.